# How can I force a Perl script to use ActiveState's wperl?

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl

I have a Perl script that requires two command line arguments that takes a while to run. I am using ActiveState Perl to run it. I can call it with

```
wperl script.pl arg1 arg2
```

from a command prompt and it runs in the background fine. If I change the .pl association from perl.exe to wperl.exe and call it with

```
script.pl arg1 arg2
```

the arguments don’t get passed. Is there something similar to the `#!/usr/bin/perl` like I can use to force `wperl` to get used?

Comment: Do we really need a '`wperl`' tag? *( This is the only question with that tag )*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is change the file association with regards to *wperl.exe* in the *Tools > Folder Options > File Types* in any Explorer window and update the *.pl* extension through *Advanced > Open > Edit command line* to

```
{Path to wperl}\wperl.exe "%1" %*
```

This ensures that all the command line arguments (%*) are passed to *wperl.exe* whenever you call your script using

```
script.pl arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 10):

The Perlmonks node [wperl.exe vs perl.exe](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=383211) suggests associating the *.wpl* extension with wperl. Name all the scripts that you want to run under wperl with a *.wpl* extension and the other *.pl* named files use the normal *perl.exe*.

Answer (score 0):

```
unless ($^X =~ m/wperl\.exe$/i) {
    exec "wperl",$0,@ARGV;
    exit 0;
}
```